# Get UserID (not Identity.Name) inside Action Filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I need to find `UserID` in an **Action Filter** of an ASP.Net MVC application. I can get the same in a normal controller as shown below.

[image]

I know how to get UserName in Action Filter.

[image]

But when I try to get UserID, I get error

```
string userID = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserID();
```

> Error CS1061  'IIdentity' does not contain a definition for 'GetUserID' and no extension method 'GetUserID' accepting a first argument of type 'IIdentity' could be found

How to get UserID inside Action Filter?

**Update - REFERENCE:**

1. [ClaimsIdentityExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/626362d8a22625e82a2af1b7076796f161510a97/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/ClaimsIdentityExtensions.cs#L6)

**Code for Action Filter**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;////Not used
using System.Linq;////Not used
using System.Web;////Not used
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; ////Not used

namespace MyPortal
{
    public class ActionFilterSessionCheck : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string userName = null;
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

                //ERROR***
                //string userID = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserID();

            }

            string sessionLogin = "Login" + userName;
            if (userName == null || (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionLogin] == null))
            {

                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    //AJAX request
                    throw new Exception("Session time out");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Standard request
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                       new RouteValueDictionary
                                       {
                                       { "action", "Login" },
                                       { "controller", "Account" }
                                       });
                }
            }


            //Call standard behavior
            this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: even adding that code  in filters will get error, if you need id, you need to check from db manually by name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you need is `GetUserId`, not `GetUserID`. It is defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityextensions.getuserid(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId%28System.Security.Principal.IIdentity%29).

The difference between your working example and your error is simply that you wrongly use `ID` instead of `Id`.